# Lodash map and return unique

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have a lodash variable;

```
var usernames = _.map(data, 'usernames');
```

which produces the following;

```
[
    "joebloggs",
    "joebloggs",
    "simongarfunkel",
    "chrispine",
    "billgates",
    "billgates"
]
```

How could I adjust the lodash statement so that it only returns an array of unique values? e.g.

```
var username = _.map(data, 'usernames').uniq();
```

Comment: have you tried `uniqBy`? `_.uniqBy(data, 'username')`

Comment: I wish the data could let me do that... but on this occasion, I can't.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Many ways, but `uniq()` isn't a method on array, it's a lodash method.

```
_.uniq(_.map(data, 'usernames'))
```

Or:

```
_.chain(data).map('usernames').uniq().value()
```

(The second is untested and possibly wrong, but it's close.)

As mentioned in the comment, depending on what your data actually *is*, you could do this all in one shot without first pulling out whatever `usernames` is.

Comment: Thanks, although I mentioned something lodash specific. I am aware about uniq() being lodash.

Comment: @KarlBateman Right, but you're trying to call a lodash method on an array. That's not how lodash works; it doesn't modify prototypes.

Comment: Thanks for this, more concisely `_(data).map('usernames').uniq().value();`

Answer (score 19):

You can also use `uniqBy` function which also accepts iteratee invoked for each element in the array. It accepts two arguments as below, where **id** is the iteratee parameter.

```
_.uniqBy(array, 'id')
```

Comment: You need one more step: `_.map(_.uniqBy(array, 'id'), 'id')` (If the number of duplicates is ginormous and the objects are small, this approach might be more performant than the accepted answer because the intermediary array will be shorter).

Answer (score 0):

very simple solution:

```
_.uniq(array.map(({ status }) => status))
```